# Filter frequencies in matlab's spectrogram

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrogram

I have a huge data from my experiments on which I am performing a short-term fft. For this I use, Matlab's [spectrogram](http://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html). The minimum meaningful frequency that can come out of this analysis is given by Rayleigh frequency (1/window-size). For my analysis I use a window size of 0.05 second. So my meaningful minimum frequency would be 20 Hz.

Now, I'd like to filter out 0 to 20 Hz in my spectrogram that matlab produces.
How do I do this with spectrogram function?

P.S: I'm a newbie to matlab. So any help from matlab experts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not so much a Matlab problem as one of fundamentals of Signal processing. If you want frequencies below 20 Hz, you'll need to take the STFT over longer timespans, just as you explained. It takes at least one oscillation to recognize a frequency. So for 1 Hz frequency bins you'll need 1 sec windows. You can however overlap the windows. There is a limit to how much this makes sense, which is automatically given in more advanced spectrogram algorithms (gabor spectrogram uses a gaussian window , google time-frequency toolbox in matlab for a 90s era French Matlab toolbox that was very good)

Comment: @roadrunner66: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I'd like to 'filter out' 0 to 20 Hz frequencies. I have done this easily in LABVIEW. (where I use a high pass filter to the time series and channel the output to a spectral analyser (PSD)). But matlab is new for me and I see a learning curve ahead. :)